# getting error:401, code = 32; message = "Could not authenticate you." in Twitter directMessage API

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

The code snippet is :

```
-(void)postMessageToFriend:(NSString *)ID {

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json?"];
NSString *text=@"Whose got next!";
NSDictionary *p =@{@"text":text,@"user_id":ID};
   SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest  requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:url parameters:p];

   [postRequest setAccount:accnt];
   [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error){
       NSError *jsonError = nil;
       NSDictionary *friendsdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
       NSLog(@"response value is: %@ %ld ",friendsdata,(long)[urlResposnse statusCode]);
   }];

   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

When I hit the API, get error code 38. Please Help.
So that I can post message to the followers individualy. or if any other solution please advice.